# Deployment-specific robots.txt with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, seo

I would like to include a public/robots.txt file with the staging deployment of my Meteor app (at *.meteor.com), basically to avoid this version of the site to be crawled at all. How can I achieve this? I'm using the `meteor deploy` command to deploy to staging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a (hopefully temporary?) solution, use a deployment script that creates public/robots.txt before invoking `meteor deploy` and at the end deletes public/robots.txt.

## The Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import os.path

dpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
if dpath:
  os.chdir(dpath)

if not os.path.exists('public'):
  os.makedirs('public')
robots = None
try:
  with open('public/robots.txt', 'wb') as robots:
    robots.write("""User-agent: *
Disallow: /
""")

  subprocess.check_call(["meteor", "deploy", '<myapp>.meteor.com'])
finally:
  if robots is not None:
    os.remove(robots.name)
```

Comment: Google can't really crawl your site at all without the spiderable package. Perhaps your script could simply call `meteor remove spiderable`, then `meteor deploy`, then `meteor add spiderable`? Or just comment out the associated line in `.meteor/packages`.

Comment: @sbking Hmm, I think it would be just an implementation detail whether to add robots.txt or e.g. remove spiderable. Shouldn't matter.